# Autofill for credit card expiry date - How to use 4 digit year?

Tags: android, autofill

take a look at the documentation for autofill [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#AUTOFILL_HINT_CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRATION_DATE)
. Specifically AUTOFILL_HINT_CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRATION_DATE constant.  So i have set up auto fill in oreo emulator and it works great for getting the users credit card info that was stored.  But the issue is the expiry date is coming from autofill in the format "09/19" but i need it as "09/2019".  From the docs it says we can override **`getAutofillType() to return AUTOFILL_TYPE_DATE.`**

I dont get it ? because this way it will return epoch time'date to me.  How do i get it to return the date in the format i desire ?

Google gave instructions how to do this:

> You define a date autofill value for the view by overriding the following methods:

- getAutofillType() to return AUTOFILL_TYPE_DATE.
- getAutofillValue()    to return a date autofillvalue.
- autofill(AutofillValue) to expect a    data autofillvalue.

given that here is what i have so far in a custom editText:

```
public class AutoFillDateFormEditText extends AppCompatEditText{
    public AutoFillDateFormEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AutoFillDateFormEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoFillDateFormEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    public int getAutofillType() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            return AUTOFILL_TYPE_DATE;
        }
        else return super.getAutofillType();
    }

    @Override
    public void autofill(AutofillValue value) {
        super.autofill(value); //what goes here ? im lost
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public AutofillValue getAutofillValue() {
        return //what should i return here ????
    }
}
```

Even if i hold breakpoints on the recommended overrides only getAutofillType() gets a break point hit, the rest of the overrided methods are not hit.  i downloaded the google sample app "autofill Sample" and tried it and the date is also not working. so i dont think its me doing something wrong yet. I am testing on a oreo emulator api 26 Nexus 6P.

the same instructions are here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#PickerAutofill

but seem to not be currently working(at least on emulator) with system auto fill service.

Answer (score 1):

you need to override `autofill` in order to set the desired format.
you need to override `getAutofillValue` in order to let the class convert an input in your edit text to an AutoFill object.

```
public class AutoFillDateFormEditText extends AppCompatEditText {



public AutoFillDateFormEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AutoFillDateFormEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AutoFillDateFormEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public int getAutofillType (){
    return AUTOFILL_TYPE_DATE;
}



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public void autofill(AutofillValue value) {
    if (!value.isDate()) {
        Timber.w(value + " could not be autofilled into " + this);
        return;
    }

    long autofilledValue = value.getDateValue();

    // First autofill it...
    setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(autofilledValue)));
    // ...then move cursor to the end.
    final CharSequence text = getText();
    if ((text != null)) {
        Selection.setSelection((Spannable) text, text.length());
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Nullable
@Override
public AutofillValue getAutofillValue() {
    final AutofillValue autofillValue = super.getAutofillValue();
    if ( autofillValue == null)
        return null;
    final Date date = tryParse(autofillValue.getTextValue().toString());
    return date != null ? AutofillValue.forDate(date.getTime()) : autofillValue;
}

private final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");

java.util.Date tryParse(String dateString)
{
    try
    {
        return dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Format the Date using SimpleDateFormat.

`DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy", Locale.ENGLISH);

 DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");

 Date date = originalFormat.parse("09/19");`

Comment: Thanks for responding.  i cannot gaurantee the date will be "09/19". this is why google gave many examples of how the date can come in:  go back and look here as i posted:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#AUTOFILL_HINT_CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRATION_DATE .  so i need a way for the system to give me back epoch time and then i can convert it. but i dont know how to get the epoch time.